# Add new column to each data.frame in list of data.frames

Tags: r, dataframe, r-caret

I have a list of data.frames and would like to use the R package caret to create a new column in each data.frame, `folds`. So far I tried to write a custom function and then apply it to my list using map. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
library(caret)

one = airquality[1:10,]
two = airquality[11:20,]
listdf <- list(one, two)

foldfunc <- function(x) {
  folds <- createFolds(1:nrow(x), k=10,list = F)
  x$folds <- folds
}

map(listdf, foldfunc)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to make your function returns the data frame:

```
foldfunc <- function(x) {
  folds <- createFolds(1:nrow(x), k=10,list = F)
  x$folds <- folds
  return(x)
}
```

In your code, your function is returning the `folds`. Since you weren't explicitly saying what to return, the function assumes that the desired result is the last thing it calculates, and that's why you were receiving numerical vectors (with the folds calculated by `createFolds`).

If you try `print(foldfunc(listdf[[1]]))` with your function, you will see this:

```
print(foldfunc(listdf[[1]]))
# [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

With the new version, a data frame with a `folds` column will be provided.

Answer (score 1):

Using `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
listdf <- map(listdf, ~ .x %>% 
     mutate(folds = createFolds(row_number(), k = 10, list = FALSE)))
```